# Is it possible to give more than one iteration in forloop

Tags: php

I don't want to use nested forloop

```
for($i=0;$j=0;$i<count('$_POST['name']');$j<count('$_POST['range']');$i++;$j++)
{
  //some code...
}
```

Comment: If number of iterations for every variable is different, how are you going to use the variable with smaller number of iterations? In general case of lopping through 2 indexes it's impossible.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh For the same number of counts there is no need for the second variable: we can use 1 variable twice.

Comment: use the same variable and instead of _;_ use _,_ like this:
`for($i=0;$i<count('$_POST['name']'),$i<count('$_POST['range']');$i++)`
or use _&&_ instead of _,_ for boolean AND.
Of course if you need the _j_ for something in code and need to work with it (change value...) simply use it, but use _,_ separators:
`for($i=0,$j=0;$i<count('$_POST['name']'),$j<count('$_POST['range']');$i++,$j++)`

Comment: Just write the nested loop and stop complaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is, you have to use a ',' (comma) instead of a ';' (semicolon) :

```
for($i=0, $j=0;
    $i<count('$_POST['name']'), $j<count('$_POST['range']');
    $i++, $j++)
{

}
```

Note that you could / may have to change the second expression of your for loop to get it to work as intended with a `&&` or a `||` :

```
$i<count('$_POST['name']') && $j<count('$_POST['range']');
```